# SQL: How to add calculated column with the text being different than the value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a column in a table which contains a path to a file in my db. I want to display this column in my asp.net web application, but I don't want to display the path in the GridView, I want the column in each row to just contain the text "View Attachment", and when it is clicked I want to be able to get the real data value of the specific column. If i remember correctly I have once achieved this with Union, but it was so long ago, I really do not recall how this is done.

Currently this is my Sql Query before my attempt to add the calculated column.

```
SELECT id, 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), updatedate) AS updateDate, 
       statusupdate 
FROM   tblproject 
WHERE  ( [id] = @id )
```

The column name in my table which contains the path is called path.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just select the 'View Attachment' as a constant value for each row. I'm not sure why you would want to do this in sql instead of c#, but...

```
SELECT path, 
       'View Attachment' AS Text 
FROM   tblproject 
WHERE  id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a formatted HTML link in your SQL statement, e.g.

```
SELECT id, 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), updatedate)            AS updateDate, 
       statusupdate, 
       '<a href="' + path + '">View Attachment</a>' AS path 
FROM   tblproject 
WHERE  ( [id] = @id )
```

As an alternative you can use GridView's [IntializeRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.initializerow(v=vs.110).aspx) event to format cell in code.

Comment: Thanks but I don't really know how to execute this html code in c#... and also the query must be inside an SQLdatasource for hierarchy in my telerik grid. How can achieve what I want with out the html code but still access the path whilst the text displayed different?

Comment: Actually I suggest looking into `GridHyperLinkColumn` then. It allows you to separate link from text

Comment: I just found an even better solution, there is a column called attachment built into telerik radgrid! Thanks though the GridHyperLinkColumn idea lead me to the attachment field!

Answer (score 0):

Never try to solve your UI problems in the database layer.

You return some piece of HTML markup and you're happy in the ASP.NET page, but what happens when you need the same data to be exposed via a web service, or shown in a WPF application or exported to a text file? Maybe you create a new query for each of them.

Need my suggestion? Only use queries like this when you need the data to be processed independent of the UI technology, like calculating averages.

Just use a`TemplateColumn` inside your `DataGrid`.